# Design pattern Microsoft recommends for custom developement

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, patterns-and-practices, design-patterns

Which design pattern Microsoft recommends for custom development?

I know these 3:

1. Model-View-Presenter Pattern
2. Service Locator pattern
3. Model-View-ViewModel Pattern

Answer (score 1):

According to [Usama Wahab Khan](https://twitter.com/@usamawahabkhan), Senior Solution Architect for SharePoint and Microsoft Technologies it's these four patterns:

> - Model-View-Presenter (MVP)
>
> [image: Model-View-Presenter (MVP)]
>
> - Repository
>
> [image: Repository]
>
> - Service Locator
>
> [image: Service Locator]
>
> - The Trusted Façade Pattern
>
> [image: The Trusted Façade Pattern]

Reference: [Most Important Design Patterns for SharePoint Developers](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/articles/pages/most-important-design-patterns-for-sharepoint-developers-.aspx)